# Django redirect to a specifc place on the page with fstring

Tags: django, django-views, httpresponse

I am trying to redirect someone after completion of the form but keep getting errors

```
self.success_url = redirect(reverse('circles') + '#circle' + str(circle.id))
```

it gives me this error:

> 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'format'

I've tried:

```
self.success_url = redirect(reverse('circles') + f'#circle{circle.id}')
```

Comment: How do you use the self.success_url? And I think it should be just string, but you give it to the redirect function. 
Can you just try this? `self.success_url = f"{reverse('circles')}#circle{circle.id}"; print(self.success_url); return redirect(self.success_url)`

Comment: That did the trick, you little genius!!! spent a whole day on this. i didnt use the return because there are more steps before that but thank you!!